# glassfish is not accessible, even though domain started

Tags: java, glassfish, server

I have had glassfish installed and running on my server for a few weeks now everything was working fine but today its behaving very weirdly,

I first tried to access the admin page but it wouldnt load, so i tried to stop the domain, when I ran asadmin stop-domain domain1, the command just sat there doing nothing, tried starting the domain again, it said the domain is already running.

so I restarted the server. Still had the same issue, then went to taskmanager and stopped the glassfish server from there, started the domain again from asadmin.

now on localhost:4848 it shows the page for glassfish server is loading but nothing happens beyond that, once it showed me the login page but after I entered the credentials it didn't go any further just kept loading, non of the applications on the server are also accessible.

I checked the logs and there is nothing abnormal there just shows the regular server loading logs. My firewall is also disabled.

At this point I am completely stumped about what else I could try.

one of the application page finally loaded after a long time it is showing gc overhead limit reached, so apparently i have a memory leak somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your DNS is working properly. Check `host localhost`, `host servername.example.com` and whatever the IP address that is returned for that with `host <ipaddr>` to make sure you are getting proper DNS resolution for all three items.